# Error Code 1824 - Failed to open the referenced table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create my DB project on MySQL, and when I tried to add foreign keys, it show the error code 1824 on all of the tables I'm trying to create. My code is this:

```
create table cliente (
id_cliente varchar(20) not null primary key,
nome varchar(50) unique not null,
endereco varchar(70) not null,
celular varchar(15) not null,
id_cartao_cliente int not null,
cod_encomenda_cliente int not null,
constraint fk_cartao foreign key (id_cartao_cliente) references cartao_credito(id_cartao),
constraint fk_encomenda foreign key (cod_encomenda_cliente) references encomenda(cod_encomenda)
) engine = innodb;

create table cartao_credito (
id_cartao int not null primary key,
num_cartao varchar(20) not null,
nome_cartao varchar(30) not null,
mes_validade varchar(2) not null,
ano_validade year,
id_cliente_cartao varchar(20) not null,
constraint fk_cliente foreign key (id_cliente_cartao) references cliente(id_cliente)
) engine = innodb;

create table Encomenda (
cod_encomenda int not null primary key,
tipo varchar(15) not null,
valor_encomenda varchar(10) not null,
local_destino varchar(20) not null,
id_destinatario_encomenda varchar(20) not null,
constraint fk_destinatario foreign key (id_destinatario_encomenda) references destinatario(id_destinatario)
) engine = innodb;

create table movimentacao (
id varchar(50) not null primary key,
local_movimentacao varchar(50) not null,
descricao varchar(30) not null,
data_movimentacao date not null,
hora_movimentacao time not null,
cod_encomenda_movimentacao int not null,
id_entregador_movimentacao varchar(20) not null,
foreign key (cod_encomenda_movimentacao) references encomenda(cod_encomenda),
foreign key (id_entregador_movimentacao) references entregador(id_entregador)
) engine = innodb;

create table entregador (
id_entregador varchar(20) not null primary key,
nome varchar(50) unique not null,
placa_veiculo varchar(10) not null,
tipo_veiculo varchar(15) not null,
cod_encomenda_entregador varchar(50) not null,
id_destinatario_entregador varchar(20) not null,
foreign key (cod_encomenda_entregador) references encomenda(cod_encomenda),
foreign key (id_destinatario_entregador) references destinatario(id_destinatario)
) engine = innodb;

create table destinatario (
id_destinatario varchar(20) not null primary key,
nome  varchar(50) not null unique not null,
endereco varchar(70) not null,
celular varchar(15) not null,
cod_encomenda_destinatario int not null,
foreign key (cod_encomenda_destinatario) references encomenda(cod_encomenda)
) engine = innodb;
```

I need help with this code please.

P.S.: all of the columns are written in Portuguese

Answer (score 0):

MySQL error code 1824 is "Failure to open referenced table."
I believe you are running into trouble because of the order you are creating in.  I see that "Encomenda" does not have a foreign key, and may be a good place to start your creation.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is wrong. Because when an entity in `cliente` refer to `cartao_credito` it means there is a (1 to N) relation between these two table. So no need to refer `cartao_credito` to `cliente` again. If you need an N to N relationship use a bridge (a new table) between them and use two 1 to N relationship.

In your design all tables refer to each other mutually. For example in two first table you need just one foreign key to join these two tables not two foreign key.